# Persist changes to docker-compose containers into new images

Tags: docker, docker-compose, prometheus, grafana

I am creating a test environment which hopefully is reproducible.

With `docker-compose`, I started a plain vanilla `grafana/grafana:latest`, a `prom/prometheus:latest` and a `gcr.io/cadvisor/cadvisor` image.

Then I had to configure things for it to all work together. I have added the prometheus data source to the grafana instance, and also added visualization graphs to it.

How do I save, export or commit now everything such that it can be restarted somewhere else and it all works again? For now I am just locally `docker-compose start/stop`, but that's only for locally.

I found `docker commit` which I could be running on each image (basically though it's only the grafana one which needs saving). But everyone says that's discouraged, and suggest a `Dockerfile` approach. But I am not sure I know all pieces I need to extract from the current grafana image (datasources, dashboards) in order to somehow stitch my new image together...

So how do I best do it?

Comment: "I ran some manual commands" intrinsically isn't reproducible.  Can you write some sort of script to configure the things that need to be configured?  Using the unmodified upstream images, plus some sort of configuration script or Ansible or Terraform or setup container, could be a good way to go here.

Comment: I did not run some manual commands, but made changes via the grafana UI...

Comment: I think this https://superuser.com/questions/1477291/grafana-provisioning-dashboards-in-docker provides the answer!